# Can an rmarkdown code chunk switch on output type?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to control how code executes depending on the output type. For example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(cars, aes(x=dist, y=speed)) + geom_point()
if (output_to_html)
  ggplotly(p)
else 
  p
```

Is there a way to know within a RMarkdown code chunk what the output type is? I didn't find what I wanted in `knitr::opts_current$get()`